# Multiple HttpWebRequests in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a windows form application that reads a bunch of urls(~800) from a text file to List. The application then shows the status code of all the urls.

The problem is If I run a normal for loop from 0 to list count, it takes a lot of time. I need to speed up the process to the maximum possible without blocking the UI. Below is my code

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("urls.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            pages.Add(line);

        }
        file.Close();

      for(int i=0; i<pages.Count; i++)
      {
               HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pages[i]);
                         int code = 0;
                         try
                         {

                             WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

                             HttpWebResponse r = (HttpWebResponse)response;

                             code = (int)r.StatusCode;
                         }
                         catch (WebException we)
                         {
                             var r = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
                             code = (int)r;
                         }
       }
  //add the url and status code to a datagridview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use tasks, so that you are not waiting for the last request to complete, before starting the next.

```
  Task<int> tasks;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    tasks = Task.Run<int>(() =>
      {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pages[i]);
        int code = 0;
        try
        {

          WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

          HttpWebResponse r = (HttpWebResponse)response;

          code = (int)r.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
          var r = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
          code = (int)r;
        }

        return code;
      }
    );
  }
  await tasks;
```

Comment: No noticeable change in speed using this.